# Observable switchMap filter toArray

Tags: typescript, filter, toarray

I'm trying to filter episodes with `switchMap` & `filter` :

```
this.getEpisodesForStoryEvents()
    .switchMap(episodes => Observable.from(episodes))
    .filter((episode: Episode) => {
        return episode.ref.startsWith('SE/8');
    })
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(episodes => {
        console.log(episodes);
    });
```

But when using `toArray`, it doesn't work anymore, I don't subscribe to anything :/

Comment: `toArray` only executes when the source observable completes. Are you sure that happens? Can you post the code of `this.getEpisodesForStoryEvents`?

Comment: `return this.db.collection('episodes-se').valueChanges();` - I'm using firebase actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `valueChanges` is an event emitter. I assume it emits an event every time that collection changes. There can always be more changes, so `valueChanges` never calls `complete`, and `toArray` waits forever.

You can't use `toArray` here. Must subscribe to the observable and process each entry as it comes. Or you could use `reduce` and add the items to an array yourself. Only that `reduce` is called for every new value pushed into the source observable, so you get updated with every change that passes the filter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a late answer :)
but simple solution for the problem can be :

```
this.getEpisodesForStoryEvents()
      .switchMap(episodes => {
        return Observable.from(episodes))
      .filter((episode: Episode) => {
        return episode.ref.startsWith('SE/8');
      })
      .toArray()
       }
  .subscribe(episodes => {
      console.log(episodes);
    });
```

So I just encapsulate the filter and toArray inside the switchMap